# ConstraintLayout buttons going off screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

My `ConstraintLayout` works fine when using it on my phone, but on my friends phone some buttons don't show on the screen.

How would I fix this?

Is it possible to convert it to some other type of layout, while not having to redesign everything?

This is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/clubname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/club_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/EditDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EditDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="285dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/date_button"
        android:onClick="sendButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/eventName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EditDate" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:onClick="sendButton"
        android:text="@string/send"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

-Tiebe

Comment: It's hard to say what the right solution is from what you posted, but those are suspiciously large margins. Don't use margins to position *where* items are on the screen or it will break on different screen sizes. Use ConstraintLayout entries to position where things are, and margins to set minimum/desired gaps between items. If you do need the large margins set them in a dimens.xml file so you can make different versions for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the hardcoded top margin of the `EditDate`, and center it vertically in parent with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Also add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to the bottom `button` so that you can make sure it won't get beyond the bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/clubname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/club_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/EditDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EditDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/date_button"
        android:onClick="sendButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/eventName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EditDate" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:onClick="sendButton"
        android:text="@string/send"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```